# Unhandled Exception Overflow Winforms app

Tags: graphics

Overflow error.Inner Exception is :Stack Trace:   at System.Drawing.Graphics.CheckErrorStatus(Int32 status)
   at System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawPath(Pen pen, GraphicsPath path)

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to draw scan plane on DICOM image for next scan using just Leadtools AnnLineObject but for some reason value of endpoints for one of the lines was coming as double.NaN and windows would throw above an unhandeled exception while refreshing annotation or paint event. I could never find exactly which line of code threw the exception but changing my logic to avoid NaN coordinates fixed it.